# If I have a question that I accidentally asked anonymously, can I integrate that with my account?

Tags: support

From what I've seen of SO I think this should be on meta, but I can't seem to ask an anonymous question there. If anyone knows how to migrate this to meta, feel free.

If I have an account but accidentally asked a question once without logging in, is there any way to integrate that question with my account? I want it to show up on my questions page and be associated with my user name. The browser I asked the question with still remembers me (cookies or however), but when I try to register that user with my openID, it prompts me to log out and back in again. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Still not logged in?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Either flag the question or email team@stackoverflow.com